# prove that if there exists a $v \neq 0$ with $Av \preceq 0$ then domain of $f_0$ is unbounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, convex-optimization

I want to prove that if there exists a $v \neq 0$ with $Av \preceq 0$ then domain of $f_0$ is unbounded. This is a problem in Boyd's convex optimization book.

The answer uses a sequence $x_k$ such that $||x_k||_2 \to \infty$. It then defines $v_k = x_k / ||x_k||_2$. The sequence has a convergent subsequence becasue $||v_k||_2 = 1$ for all $k$. Let $v$ be its limit, then we have $||v||_2 = 1$ and, since $a_i^T v_k < b_i / ||x_k||_2$ for all $k$, and $a_i^T v \le 0$. Therefore $Av \preceq 0$ and $v \neq 0$.

What I don't get is how do we know that there exists a convergent subsequence? And how do we get $a_i^T v \le 0$ from $a_i^T v_k < b_i / ||x_k||_2$ ? I'm guessing they use the limit and got $\lim a_i^T v_k < \lim b_i / ||x_k||_2 \implies a_i^T v < 0$ but this doesn't include $0$.

Comment: What is $A$? What is $f_0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I don't get is how do we know that there exists a convergent subsequence?

I am assuming that this is in a finite dimensional space.

The sequence is contained in the closed unit ball, which is a compact set.
In a compact set in a metric space, each sequence has a convergent subsequence.
See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem)
and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Metric_spaces).

> And how do we get $a_i^T v \le 0$ from $a_i^T v_k < b_i / ||x_k||_2$ ? I'm guessing they use the limit and got $\lim a_i^T v_k < \lim b_i / ||x_k||_2 \implies a_i^T v < 0$ but this doesn't include $0$.

We have $\|x_k\|_2\to\infty$. Then $b_i / \|x_k\|_2\to0$ follows for $k\to\infty$.
Note that when taking the limit in an "$<$" inequality, the limit only satisfies
"$\leq$" (for example, $0<1/n$ holds, but in the limit we have $0\leq 0$).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For inclusion, it should only include $0$ if $b_i > 0$. If $b_i < 0$, it never reaches $0$.

Comment: Are you saying that $\lim_{k\to\infty} b_i/\|x_k\|_2\neq0$ can hold if $b_i<0$? Because that would be false, because the limit is still $0$.

Comment: ah right. that was a silly mistake. Thank you!